# VPN-tunnel renegotiation problems

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, redis, celery

I have an application running on top of Celery with redis as a broker. Redis is hosted at our datacenter but the workers are hosted on a separate line. We have setup two-way communcation between the servers by utilizing a vpn-tunnel.

The problem with this is that it seems that the workers are sensitive to VPN-renegotiations. Our server provider does this every hour which causes our celery-workers to be disconnected from the cluster.

Does anyone had any similar problem? Is there something I'm missing? I find it very odd that my celery-workers die because they are basically polling the redis-instance.

The VPN is setup using IPSEC site to site with a fortigate r60d.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you know for sure that it is the clients and not the actual VPN connection that is the problem? Do you have keep alive configured on your VPN? In OpenVPN, you do as described in the [manual](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html) - look for keepalive. Also, `persist-key` and `persist-tun` may be necessary if using OpenVPN

Comment: Site to site IPSEC with fortigate r60d. The keep alive is set.